# How to get response code from a Https Url using java

Tags: java, http, basic-authentication

Hi am trying to fetch the response code of a https url

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.io.*;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class test
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  throws Exception
  {
     /* String userpass = "NUPuMYCGIupzhbIe05cIwH2CcIQHXlh6" + ":" + "keG4sZAP82dcJK8H";
      String basicAuth = "Basic " + javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userpass.getBytes());
*/
    String httpsURL = "https://api.devo.com/ad/v1";
    URL url = new URL ( httpsURL );
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    //connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+"lVQdU1ZQ0dJdX6aGJJZTAYl3SDJDY0lRSFhsaDY6a2VHNHNaQVA4MmRjSks4SA==");
    //String encoded = Base64.encode(username+":"+password);


    connection.connect();

    // Cast to a HttpURLConnection
    if ( connection instanceof HttpURLConnection)
    {
       HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;

       int code = httpConnection.getResponseCode();

       System.out.println(code);
    }
    else
    {
       System.err.println ("error - not a http request!");
    }
  }
}
```

Without basic auth am getting response code as 401 but when I use basic auth as you see I have commented those out

```
  //connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+"lVQdU1ZQ0ddXB6aGJJZTA1Y0l3SDJDY0lRSFhsaDY6a2VNHNaQVA4MmRjSks4SA==");
```

I am getting 500 as code but when the URL is down am getting 400 now how can I pass the basic auth and why am getting 500 as code when I pass with Basic auth?
Please suggest me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you the Apache Http Components. Take a look [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/authentication.html)

Comment: It worked for me by just un commenting connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+"lVQdU1ZQ0dJdX6aGJJZTAYl3SDJDY0lRSFhsaDY6a2VHNHNaQVA4MmRjSks4SA==");